# Apache mod_rewrite RewriteCond -U flag false positive

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is what I'm trying to do: any URI that doesn't resolve on one machine gets bumped to another via reverse proxy. The configuration looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-U
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://other.site/$1 [P,NS]
```

Now, what that is supposed to say is "if I can't find anything locally by running a subrequest, punt it to the proxy."

Only problem is, it doesn't do that. With the RewriteLogLevel jacked, I get this:

```
31.3.3.7 - - [29/Jul/2012:00:26:18 --0700] [internet.srs.bznz/sid#7fc6099fa228][rid#7fc609bf2bf0/initial] (5) RewriteCond URI (-U) check: path=/ -> status=200
31.3.3.7 - - [29/Jul/2012:00:26:18 --0700] [internet.srs.bznz/sid#7fc6099fa228][rid#7fc609bf2bf0/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='!-U' => not-matched
```

There is nothing at / on that machine. It should return 403. So my question is: where the hell is that 200 OK coming from? It's a brand-new Debian VPS, so it's not like there's any pollution in the config. I tried this same thing elsewhere (Ubuntu 12.04) and same thing.

How do I find out what's causing that errant success code?

Answer (score 4):

Same problem. Moreover, I enhanced config by adding

> `RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} =false`

as the first test condition. I think it would be neverending recursion otherwise.

But my experience is, that any existing or non-existing URI is evaluated OK (200). I don't know why, but it may test just server configuration for that URI - whether path is allowed or denied by something like `Deny from all` or `RewriteRule [F]`

Comment: **[apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond): Checks whether or not _TestString_ is a valid URL, accessible via all the server's currently-configured access controls for that path.** Thus, it checks just configured access righs, not existency or filesystem rights...